# Add comment for the author when deleting low quality post: add open text field beside preset list of reason

Tags: feature-request

Reviewing low quality post, I stumbled on an answer detected as low quality because very short (only 2 lines of code).

Beside the proposed answer was duplicating existing answer (with a slight variation) and the two lines of code where syntaxically incorrect. Beside that nobody voted for that answer and deleting the answer wouldn't affect the user rep.

Hencefore I opted for deletion and was prompted with "Add comment for the author" dialog.

But it is slightly annoying that 
- the dialog is a fixed list of predefined delete reasons
- it does include neither duplicate answer nor syntax error (code) in answer in proposed suggestions.

As no other suggestions applied, I picked "no comment needed", but I still believe the answering user should have get a comment (at least: please check code syntax before posting code).

Shouldn't there be some open text proposed as delete comment for unanticipated cases like this one?

Comment: You can add any comment you want.  I just did.

Comment: Why didn't it show up in my case ? Too bad I din't did a snapshot. Transient bug ? Cache to refresh on my browser ? I will check next time if it happens again.

Comment: @kriss Hans means (presumably) you can press _Add comment_ before opening that prompt, add a comment, and then choose _No comment needed_ in the prompt because you've already added one.

Comment: @Erik von Asmuth: Ah! Ok. In my case I didn't thought about deletion comments before the interface prompted and remembered me it would be nicer to put one (something I agree with).